# How to generate sign to pass to transferPreSigned(), contract is not asking for sign while transfer()

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, metamask

I'm creating ERC865 token so that users can send tokens without having ether. I followed [1](https://hackernoon.com/you-dont-need-ether-to-transfer-tokens-f3ae373606e1) and [2](https://medium.com/coinmonks/transfer-ethereum-tokens-without-ether-an-erc20-improvement-to-seriously-consider-90bebd447bb).

As per 1, sender will sign transaction object while calling transfer() but I'm unable to see any "Sign"! What parameters should be passed to transferPreSigned()? I'm using Metamask and Solidity.

Comment: have you seen this https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865 carefully?

Comment: @MaheshRajput Yes! By following [1](https://hackernoon.com/you-dont-need-ether-to-transfer-tokens-f3ae373606e1), came to know that transferPreSignedHashing() will return a hash generated by keccak-256 and that hash to be signed off-chain. Now this sign has to be given to transferPreSigned(). Is my flow correct? After generating sign using web3.eth.sign(), ecRecover gives the wrong address!!